# How to create a Button in android otherthan from Xml files?

Tags: android

I want to create a Button otherthan creating it from xml layout.i want to create the button in java class otherthan using any resources folder .please anyone help me to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look up the [`View`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) and [`ViewGroup`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) API documentation.

Found [this tutorial](http://www.linux-mag.com/cache/7705/1.html) which gives an example of how to do it.